# C - Separate a string by quotations then spaces

Tags: c, string

I want to separate a char* variable into a char** array by first the quotations then by spaces.

For instance,

```
char* str = "\"I am in quotes\" and I am not, however \" I am \"";
char* strCopy = malloc(strlen(str)+1)
strcpy(strCopy, str);

char** args = get_args(strCopy);

int i = 0;
while(args[i]) {
    printf("%s\n", args[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Would produce the output:

```
I am in quotes
and 
I
am
not,
however
I am
```

Part of the trouble is I also want to account for if the quotations are not closed, e.g.

```
char* str  = "\"My quotes are closed \" but \"mine are not";
```

```
My quotes are closed
but
"mine
are
not
```

I have attempted to use strtok, but I can't seem to get it to work this way.

Comment: By detecting unclosed quotes I presume you mean leaving the last starting quote if there is an odd number of quotes, otherwise how to you detect `"\"Mine are not but \"my quotes are closed \""? Anyway, separate this into two tasks; first tokenise, then remove balanced quotes.

Comment: You should show your best effort so far and explain where it goes wrong.  This is part of creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  Since `strtok()` zaps the delimiters it finds, it may not be appropriate.  You might find `strcspn()` useful.  How are double quotes embedded in a double-quoted section?

Comment: My compiler interprets double quotes with a slash in front of it as a character in the string, e.g. it would read ```char* str = "/" in quotes /"" as a string with the contents ->"in quotes"

Comment: You have still not shown what you've tried.  You've shown a test harness, which is good, but you've not shown what you've tried and explained where you're having problems.  Please do that — people won't do your homework for you, but they will help you fix problems in an honest attempt to solve the problem.  See the MCVS/MRE/SSCCE links I provided previously.  I found that the POSIX function [`strndup()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strndup.html) was quite useful (and [`strcspn()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html) too).

Comment: Should the leading and trailing blanks inside a quoted string be included in the result?  Your output for "I am" suggests that they should be removed.  What about repeated blanks within a quoted string (`"\"  before  during  and  after  \""`)?  It's often a good idea to print strings with some marker, such as `[` and `]` surrounding it (`printf("[%s]\n", args[i]);`) so that you can see where the string starts and ends and whether there are trailing blanks, etc.  It can also identify problems with `'\r'` characters embedded in data, not to mention newlines.